# Process file by line in C++ where one line is string and second is array of floats

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have this file format:

```
Jane Doe
10 3.1 8 7.4 5 10 6 8 0.1 2
```

And I want to read the file line by line, storing the first line in a string and the second line is an array of floats.

```
string name;
double scores[10];

ifstream scoreFile;
scoreFile.open(SCORES_FILENAME);

if (scoreFile) {
        
        while (getline (scoreFile,line)) {
            // ??
        }
    scoreFile.close();
    }
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Your question title specifies an array of integers while your question body specifies an array of floats. You must decide which data type you want. They are not the same.

Comment: fixed. floats, sorry.

Comment: Here's how to figure this out, this always works! Take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down a step-by-step process of doing this, as short, brief sentences in plain English. [Have your rubber duck review your plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Generally, we don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++, and you're done! Have you discussed this with your rubber duck, yet?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C++ is the problem. I know the process. Read the first line, store it as a string. Then loop over each element of the second line and store each element in an array. I just don't understand the C++ inputstream stuff.

Comment: Why not, @armin? It always works, and never fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `std::istringstream` to parse the array, eg:

```cpp
string name, line;
double scores[10];

...

getline(scoreFile, name);

getline(scoreFile, line);
std::istringstream iss(line);
for(int i = 0; (i < 10) && (iss >> scores[i]); ++i);
```